# Empty ArrayList after using Volley in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm working on a simple app where I add elements in a ListView dynamically, for this I'm using Volley to read JSON and then add all the information inside a data class, as I saw in other questions Volley is asynchronous so when I try to get the size of my list it return 0 because it was executed before Volley.

I can't figure out how to wait for volley to finish before continuing with the code in Kotlin, this is the code where I get the data:

```
    private fun getUsers() {
        val url = ""
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, {
            response ->try {
                val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("" + "data")
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val distr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

                    val getUser = distr.getString("Utilizador").toString()
                    val getCargo = distr.getString("Cargo").toString()
                    val getEstado = distr.getString("Estado").toString().toInt()
                    listUtilizadores.add(Utilizadores(getUser, getCargo, getEstado))
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
        requestQueue.add(request)
    }
```

And how I call it inside onCreate()

```
getUsers()
Log.i("Testing", "Value: " + listUtilizadores.size)
```

Thank you

Comment: You're checking for the result too soon. This function queues up a request which will finish some time in the future. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: You don't wait for Volley to finish, it's designed so your (very slow in computer terms) network requests happen in the background, and you really don't want your app to hang while it's doing internet stuff (which might not even finish if you have connectivity problems). You need to do something with the result when it comes in, like in Tenfour04's link. That means your list won't be available when you're setting up, and you'll have to update your ``ListView`` later, when the data comes in

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with JsonArrayRequest.

```
val request =JsonArrayRequest(
                   url,
                    Response.Listener { response ->
                       
                        if (response != null) {
                            for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                                try {
                                    val distr = response.getJSONObject(i)
                 val getUser = distr.getString("Utilizador").toString()
                    val getCargo = distr.getString("Cargo").toString()
                    val getEstado = distr.getString("Estado").toString().toInt()
                    listUtilizadores.add(Utilizadores(getUser, getCargo, getEstado))
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        }, { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
        requestQueue.add(request)
    }
```